# Status bar library not showing

Tags: ios

I'm using this library https://github.com/marketplacer/Dodo to show a status bar when there is no internet. But even though these codes are compiled, there is no status bar showing. I also test by replace these dodo view by UILabel, and the Label showed. But why the dodo view can not be showed. Can anyone explain me.

Here is the code:

```
if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
      load()
    } else if !Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
      view.dodo.style.label.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
      view.dodo.style.bar.backgroundColor = DodoColor.fromHexString("#00000090")
      view.dodo.style.bar.hideAfterDelaySeconds = 10
      view.dodo.style.bar.hideOnTap = true
      view.dodo.style.bar.locationTop = true
      view.dodo.style.bar.onTap = { /* Button tapped */ }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this updated code:

```
if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
      load()
    } else if !Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
      view.dodo.style.label.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
      view.dodo.style.bar.backgroundColor = DodoColor.fromHexString("#00000090")
      view.dodo.style.bar.hideAfterDelaySeconds = 10
      view.dodo.style.bar.hideOnTap = true
      view.dodo.style.bar.locationTop = true
      view.dodo.style.bar.onTap = { /* Button tapped */ }

      view.dodo.show("No Internet")

    }
```

Sample ViewController:

```
import UIKit
```

import Dodo

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    view.dodo.style.label.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
    view.dodo.style.bar.backgroundColor = DodoColor.fromHexString("#00000090")
    view.dodo.style.bar.hideAfterDelaySeconds = 10
    view.dodo.style.bar.hideOnTap = true
    view.dodo.style.bar.locationTop = true
    view.dodo.style.bar.onTap = { /* Button tapped */ }

    view.dodo.show("No Internet")

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}
```

}

[image: ScreenSHot]

If still doesn't work please check 'isConnectedToNetwork' implementation and put a debug break point in else part of your code.

Comment: I will try again, maybe it appear behind the navigation bar, I sure Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() is right.

Comment: try with this     view.dodo.topLayoutGuide = bottomLayoutGuide

Comment: It still not work, I think it doens't work with navigation bar or tableview

Comment: Yes, DODO has some issues with scrollview. What you can do is add a custom view over your tableview and show dodo message in that view.